# Вывести таблицу с форматированием строк

Tags: java

Необходимо вывести таблицу умножения с использованием форматирования строк.
В таком виде:

```
1|2|3|4|5|
___________
2|4|6|8|10|
___________
3|6|9|12|15|
```

С вертикальными разделителями разобрался, используя

```
System.out.printf("%2s|", multiplicationTable[i][j]);,
```

но горизонтальные не получается вывести

Comment: Так на каком языке нужно?

Comment: оставьте только метку нужного языка и приведите ваш код

Comment: извияюсь, на java

Comment: выводите ведь двойным вложенным циклом. вот после вложенного цикла и добавьте вывод `\n-----------\n`.

Comment: @Sayat зачем вы удалили свой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1230574/191482 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] multiplicationTable = getMutliplicationTable(); // создание таблицы умножение.
for (int i = 0; i < multiplicationTable.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < multiplicationTable[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d|", multiplicationTable[i][j]); // вывести число с дополнительными пробелами в начале, чтобы оно занимало 3 символа.
    }
    System.out.println("\n________________________________________"); // вывести 40 нижних подчеркиваний. Можно использовать "\n" + "_".repeat(40) если версия джавы 11+
}
```